# I am having the issue in wp site

Tags: wordpress, caching

I am having the following issue in wp site.

```
Warning: include(/home2/ngohost/public_html/artfinteriors.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-base.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ngohost/public_html/artfinteriors.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 65    
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home2/ngohost/public_html/artfinteriors.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-base.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/ngohost/public_html/artfinteriors.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 65    
Warning: include_once(/home2/ngohost/public_html/artfinteriors.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/ossdl-cdn.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ngohost/public_html/artfinteriors.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 82    
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home2/ngohost/public_html/artfinteriors.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/ossdl-cdn.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/ngohost/public_html/artfinteriors.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 82    
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ngohost/public_html/artfinteriors.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php:65) in /home/ngohost/public_html/artfinteriors.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1179
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using WP Super Cache plugin and this is causing the errors. The first step for debugging is to try to deactivate / uninstall the plugin and see if the error still appear.

Comment: Thank's for your help.
But i also solve this issue.That was a Theme issue.